# How do i create a function but in a different way?

Tags: python, windows, function, coding-style

*like for example:*

```
string = "me"

def print_str(n):
    print(n)

string.print()
```

> **i want to do something like this**

Comment: are you familiar with OOP?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to read up on Object Oriented Programming in python before completely understanding this, but for the sake of the question, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
class Class():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
    
    def output(self):
        print(self.text)



obj = Class("me")
obj.output()
```

output:

```
me
```

Comment: nah, i already know OOP, i want to create something like the split function in python. like where u have:
string = "hello"
string.split(' ')

like this, where u do it to a string.

Comment: That is how it's done. `split()` is a method of the string class. Also, look up the difference between methods and functions.